# React.js write components directly in HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'm very new to React.js but exploring it I expected something that I'm not able to do.

Say that I have a component:

```
var SampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Is this the only way to add it to the DOM?

```
React.render(
  <SampleComponent />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I hoped I would be able to do something like this directly in HTML after having defined the component:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <SampleComponent />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Right now I'm also looking into this matter, as I want to export my React components for others to easily implement them into their website and I think it would simplify the import if it would be possible to do so with HTML elements. The only thing which seems to come close to this is Maple.js, although I haven't looked to deep into it:
https://github.com/Wildhoney/Maple.js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using `React.render()` is the "only way" to do it.

You might be expecting something along the likes of Webcomponents where you can define you [custom elements](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/custom-elements/) and put those in your HTML but that's not the way React works (yet perhaps).

There is however a library called `x-react` where you can register those types of elements, but still it's JavaScript powered and not straight up HTML.

Comment: Thanks I *thought* I saw it somewhere before but now I'm guessing it was vuejs where you can actually declare/use components directly in the HTML file. Apparently in 2021 this can't be done in react either.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical app you would have a high-level controller-view component mounted to the DOM this way, but that component would contain a hierarchy of child components in its render method to build up the structure of your interface. This is the idea of composable views which is an advantage of react. These child components can be used directly within the jsx of the parents' render methods in the same way you had hoped, so you really only have to call `React.render` once on the top-level component.

Comment: How do you render two distinct controller-views on a page? I believe React.render() only allows for one attachment.. how would you get the other on the page?

Comment: I've not tried to do this, but I think you could have multiple React.render calls, one for each view hierarchy / mount node. But you could also just wrap them in a single component and mount that. "Controller-view" as I understand it just means a view that's managing application state, not necessarily that it's rendered in a certain way.

Comment: my bad on that question - you can attach 'n' number of React.render. I was just jacking my code up. Thanks for the reply.