# Configure If-Else Component, React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have added an `if-else` element to my React Component per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html); however, due to the syntactical differences  between including a React component with `<></>` and `{}` I am unsure of how to further configure the component.

Here is a reduced version of what I have (written in TypeScript):

```
public render() {
    const mediaElement: HTMLMediaElement = this.getMediaElement();
    return { mediaElement };
}
```

Here is `getMediaElement()` reduced:

```
private getMediaElement() {
    //... video can also be returned
    return document.createElement("audio");
    //...
}
```

From here, preferably inline, I would like to be able to add class information, etc., something akin to (as also doable in React):

```
<li className="media-file-title">
```

How do I go about accessing properties on the element with the above syntax? Ultimately, I am in need of assigning a ref. Any documentation would be great!

Is it only doable through object properties, i.e.:

`mediaElement.src = ""`

Comment: can you paste your `getMediaElement()` method implementation? I don't get if `getMediaElement()` returns a React Class or a plain html element ?

Comment: @drinchev just a plain HTML element. Posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best approach would be to render a React Element instead of plain HTML element. See [React.js write components directly in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362456/react-js-write-components-directly-in-html?rq=1) .

You can rewrite your code like :

```
private getMediaElement(src) {
    //... video can also be returned
    return (<audio src={ src } />);
    //...
}

public render() {
    const mediaElement = this.getMediaElement(this.props.src);
    return (mediaElement);
}
```

Then you can access the props of the class later via the props of your component.